# Recursive SIGSTOP

Tags: pid, kill

I can send a STOP signal to a pid using:

```
kill -STOP PID
```

And then resume it:

```
kill -CONT PID
```

How do I recursively send this to all the children of the pid in the tree as well?z

Answer (score 0):

This was to freeze fluxbox and all it's children.

So I wrote a script that does the trick.

```
fbpid="$(pgrep fluxbox)"
pidlist="$(ps h --ppid ${fbpid} -o pid)"
pnamelist="$(ps h --ppid ${fbpid} -o command)"

echo -e "We will be suspending these processes: \n${pnamelist}\n"
read -p "Continue?"

for pid in ${pidlist}
    do
    kill -STOP "$pid"
done
kill -STOP "$fbpid"

read -p "Resume fluxbox and children?"

for pid in ${pidlist}
    do
    kill -CONT "$pid"
done
kill -CONT "$fbpid"
```

Naturally, it has to be launched from tmux/screen/tty/console.